# Bootstrap grid displays columns as rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap grid

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1">Column 1</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">Column 2</div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">Column 3</div>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="Item in Items">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">{{Item.Field1}</div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">{{Item.Field2}}</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">{{Item.Field3}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It should display a 3-column grid, instead the columns are displayed as rows. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/szsSpLhyUL

Comment: see you applied  class="col-sm-1" to every where so for that it is looking like rows so remove class="col-sm-1" for items.

Comment: removing it from items did not help

Comment: check the page source to ensure the bootstrap css file is included with the correct URL.

Comment: It should only be displayed as text without Bootstrap CSS (not rows). Is it possible your own CSS replaces Bootstrap columns? Try to exclude all CSS except Bootstrap.

Comment: excluded my CSS but still the same issue

Answer (score 1):

So your first row is the like the "header" and the next row are the records.  Your header is 1-2-1 but your records are 2-4-6 => it won't line up.  To keep it from stacking even on small screens you can do col-xs-x instead.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">Column 1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">Column 2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">Column 3</div>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="Item in Items">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">{{Item.Field1}</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">{{Item.Field2}}</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">{{Item.Field3}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: keep in mind the capability of combining the column sizing eg: `class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1"` which will adjust based on viewpoint of width `25%` for extra small viewpoints (width of 0px to 544px) and width of `8.33%` on small viewpoints (width of 545px to 768px) or more if md, lg, or xl column sizes are not specified.

Comment: @ElenaDBA, hmm...you should try to inspect on the col- and see what you see on the styles...have you try the CDN of bootstrap and nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want them to always line up. Bet way to do that will be this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">Column 1<br>
        {{Item.Field1}}
      </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">Column 2<br>
        {{Item.Field2}}</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">Column 3<br>
        {{Item.Field3}}</div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can replace the br and wrap the elements in divs and display: block;

Working example here:

http://www.bootply.com/tb10AKqzM1

Comment: The other answer was closer to what you are looking for but here's a modified version with repeating elements like your loop: http://www.bootply.com/lxVZpGrIFv

Answer (score 0):

Having put in the code myself, it actually does work. It will put in rows when the viewport size is below the small viewing size (so xs, extra small size). If you want to view it on all viewing sizes then you would have to add xs instead of s to all your classes.